# Looping though preferredwirelessnetwork for removal

Tags: bash, macos

Trying to write a script that will loop though my preferred wireless networks and remove all but my home wifi network. I have somewhat working script but the problem is when it gets to the home network it gets stuck. Since it is not removed from the list when it loops again it keeps hitting that SSID until the scripts ends.

I know the issues is with how I am getting the network name but I can't think of another way to get it and have it format properly so it can be added to a list/array.

```
#!/bin/bash

WIFIDEIVCE=$(networksetup -listallhardwareports | grep "Wi-Fi" -1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}'
NETWORKLISTCOUNT=$(networksetup -listpreferredwirelessnetworks ${WIFIDEIVCE} | wc -l)


for (( i = 0; i < $NETWORKLISTCOUNT -1; i++ )); do
  NETWORKNAME=$(networksetup -listpreferredwirelessnetworks ${WIFIDEIVCE} | tail -1 | awk '{$1=$1};1' )
  if [ "$NETWORKNAME" != "home_wifi" ]; then
    networksetup -removepreferredwirelessnetwork ${WIFIDEIVCE} "$NETWORKNAME"
  else
    echo "Network is $NETWORKNAME and will not be removed"
  fi
done
```

Is there another want to get the data from listpreferredwirelessnetworks into a proper list/array so it can be looped though and properly handle the exclusion for removal?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than using a loop control variable "i", just iterate through all of the results.  We can use grep -v to eliminate "home_wifi" from the list.

We should probably use a while and read to allow for network names with spaces, but here's the for loop version to show you a different way to use for loops.

```
#!/bin/bash

WIFIDEIVCE=$(networksetup -listallhardwareports | grep "Wi-Fi" -1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}')


for NETWORKNAME in $( networksetup -listpreferredwirelessnetworks ${WIFIDEIVCE} | tail -n+2 | grep -v home_wifi )
do
  echo networksetup -removepreferredwirelessnetwork ${WIFIDEIVCE} "$NETWORKNAME"
done
```

Here's the same code organized in a while loop to avoid issues when there are spaces in your network names:

```
#!/bin/bash

WIFIDEIVCE=$(networksetup -listallhardwareports | grep "Wi-Fi" -1 | tail -1 | awk '{print $2}')


networksetup -listpreferredwirelessnetworks ${WIFIDEIVCE} | tail -n+2 | grep -v home_wifi  |
while
  read NETWORKNAME
do
  echo networksetup -removepreferredwirelessnetwork ${WIFIDEIVCE} "$NETWORKNAME"
done
```

I've left the 'echo' in the code to avoid issues for other readers who may copy and paste this code.

Comment: Yes this worked perfectly. Thanks for the help and breaking it down.